# Emacs and IPython integration: multiple lines sent

Tags: ipython

I am using emacs with Anaconda's IPython console:

```
(setq python-shell-interpreter (substitute-in-file-name "$HOME/anaconda3/bin/ipython"))
```

IPython opens after C-c C-p, but always with four empty input lines at the beginning:

[image: emacs and ipython]

Also, when I send a command by selecting a region and C-c C-r (`print('words')`) in this case, again four empty lines show up and then the result:

[image: print words]

How to fix this? I don't have any IPython related configuration apart from the line that I pasted at the top.

Comment: Why won't people help? I have a similar issue and I don't even know where to begin!